# Adding integer array column with rails migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.4

I want to add migration that will do the same as:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN int_array integer[];
```

with result column: **int_array, type: integer[], storage: extendent**

I tried these options, but it doesn't work.

```
def change
  add_column :my_table, :int_array, :integer, array: true, default: [] #first option
  add_column :my_table, :int_array, :integer, array: true, default: '{}' #second options
end
```

Errors that occurred:

```
==  AddIntArrayToMyTable: migrating ==========================================
-- add_column(:my_table, :int_array, :integer, {:array=>true, :default=>[]})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: incorrect syntax for input integer: "--- []
"
: ALTER TABLE "my_table" ADD COLUMN "int_array" integer DEFAULT '--- []
```

and

```
==  AddIntArrayToMyTable: migrating ==========================================
-- add_column(:my_table, :int_array, :integer, {:array=>true, :default=>"{}"})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: incorrect syntax for input integer: "{}"
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?
I'm using rails Rails 3.2.16 and postgreSQL 9.4

Thanks in advence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with **execute** method.

```
def up
  execute "ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN int_array integer[];"
end

def down
  execute "ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN int_array;"
end
```